# Cannot login on virtual terminal - return repeating?

Tags: virtual-console

My Ubuntu 18.04.2 system is working OK except for the following problem:

I cannot seem to be able to login on any of the virtual terminals (Ctrl+Alt+F1 to F6. Specifically, I can type my username fine, and the keyboard works without a problem, no unusual behaviour, until I press Return (or Enter on the keypad).

At that point, the password prompt appears but immediately it is as if Return is pressed again, so entering a blank password and giving Login incorrect. The login prompt reappears but again it is as if Return is immediately pressed, again giving Login incorrect. The repeats a few more times until the screen clears and the login prompt shows again. Now Return does not keep repeating.

Any ideas? The Return key is working no problem in graphical mode.

Answer (score 1):

It is not unlikely that you are hit by this issue. Removing the gpm feature fixed it for me. It happened around the time I posted on that bug.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gpm/+bug/1814261

The official bug (where developers are working on resolving the issue) is here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1813873

It looks like something was not backported and as a result the missing code generate that auto-return problem. It should be fixed soon. The fix was pushed around the 20th (Feb 2019.)